Simultaneously Serial reading and writing
I have a project that requires simultaneously serial reading and writing. I recieve some data from Arduino and show them in the relevant area in the interface. In the exact time while reading I need to send some data to Arduino via serial. Each reading and writing work perfectly on their own. But if I start a write task while the read task is running, the read task stops. After the writing is finished, the reading continues from where it left off. I know that reading and writing work at same time. But I couldn't make it work.
Here is the script which do reading process
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using TMPro;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine.Events;
 
public class Serial : MonoBehaviour{

    // stream variable
    public SerialPort stream = new SerialPort();
    public string receivedString = "";
    // threading
    Thread readThread;
    private static List<Action> executeOnMainThread = new List<Action>();

    public void StartConnection()
    {
        stream.PortName = "COM4";
        stream.BaudRate = 9600;
        stream.ReadTimeout = 600000;
        stream.WriteTimeout = 600000;
    
        if (!stream.IsOpen)
        {
            stream.Open();
            readThread = new Thread(ReadFromSerial);
            readThread.Start();
        }
    }
    void ReadFromSerial()
    {
        while (stream.IsOpen)
        {
            string value = stream.ReadLine();
    Debug.Log(value);
            stream.BaseStream.Flush();
        }
    }
    void Update () 
    {
        lock (executeOnMainThread)
        {
            foreach (var action in executeOnMainThread)
            {
                action();
            }
            executeOnMainThread.Clear();
        }
    }  
}

And here is the writing task scripts
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using TMPro;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class SimulationHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject serialobject;
    private Serial serial;
    
    string presureCSVFileName = "";
    List<string> presureData = new List<string>();

    // threading
    Thread simPThread;
    void Start()
   {
        serial = serialobject.GetComponent<Serial>(); 
    }
    
    public void SelectCSV()
    {
        presureCSVFileName = "C:/Users/Pc/Downloads/simp.csv";
        GetPresureData();
    }

    void GetPresureData()
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(presureCSVFileName))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                string[] cells = line.Split(',');
                presureData.Add(cells[3]);
            }
        }
    }
    void SIMPThreadFunction()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < presureData.Count ; i++)
        {
            if (serial.stream.IsOpen)
            {
                string simpData = presureData[i];
                serial.stream.Write(simpData);
                serial.stream.BaseStream.Flush();
                Debug.Log(simpData);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }     
        }
        Debug.Log("SIMP done!");
    }

    public void SIMP()
    {
        Debug.Log("SIMP start!");
        simPThread = new Thread(SIMPThreadFunction);
        simPThread.Start();
    }
}

I tried to share the relevant code by deleting the irrelevant ones.
Could it be buffer problem or something else? How could I manage this task? I hope you guys help me. Thank you in advance.

It was because of Arduino. The unity code is working very well. I tried the program while connected to Xbee and all worked. Arduino cannot read and write simultaneously that's why I couldn't receive any data while sending data to Arduino. And I have thought that my unity code is wrong but no! The problem was Arduino.
